# How to convert Click event of mega menu to hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I found a nice Mega menu which need some modification so that it can be used with ASP.Net webform application.

Besides that this mega menu works on the Click event which may confuse user at time as usually most of the user are used to hover effect over the menus.

How can i change click even to hover so that that when user hover over the menu it show up till user moves mouse out of the menu are of dropdown. This is a responsive menu design & may have been designed intentionally for click event.

http://jsfiddle.net/9fmfC/1/

```
    $(function() {
        cbpHorizontalMenu.init();
    });
```

Actual Example: http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/HorizontalDropDownMenu/

Note: Please increase the width of the `Result1 area of  jsFiddle to the view of larger screen otherwise it will adjust to small screen view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script works completely :)

```
var cbpHorizontalMenu = (function() {

var $listItems = $( '#cbp-hrmenu > ul > li' ),
    $menuItems = $listItems.children( 'a' ),
    $body = $( 'body' ),
    current = -1;

function init() {
    $menuItems.on( 'mouseover', open );
    $listItems.on( 'mouseover', function( event ) { event.stopPropagation();} );
            $listItems.on( 'mouseleave', close );
}

function open( event ) {

    if( current !== -1 ) {
        $listItems.eq( current ).removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
    }

    var $item = $( event.currentTarget ).parent( 'li' ),
        idx = $item.index();

    if( current === idx ) {
        $item.removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
        current = -1;
    }
    else {
        $item.addClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
        current = idx;
    }

    return false;

}

function close( event ) {
    $listItems.eq( current ).removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
    current = -1;
}

return { init : init };

})();
```

Comment: Your code (ahem) also does not work completely. http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/SZdmK/

Comment: @Xotic750 Ok, I forgot to mention that I tested it directly in Mozilla Firefox (18), there it works.

Comment: @NieldsC, Code is not working properly sometime it hides & sometimes not & if you move mouse below the menu then it doesnt hide menu. Logically it should work like a normal drop down menu ....

Comment: Damnit, I replied too quickly. It doesn't work properly indeed, I'm sorry.

Comment: I edited the script so it closes when you leave the menu at the bottom. Tested it in Firefox

Answer (score 3):

Well it required that you modify the [javascript source of the menu](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/HorizontalDropDownMenu/js/cbpHorizontalMenu.min.js).

So it should look something like this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        <nav id="cbp-hrmenu" class="cbp-hrmenu">
            <ul>
                <li>    <a href="#">Products</a>

                    <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                        <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
                            <div>
                                    <h4>Learning &amp; Games</h4>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Catch the Bullet</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Snoopydoo</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Fallen Angel</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sui Maker</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Wave Master</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Golf Pro</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                    <h4>Utilities</h4>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Gadget Finder</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Green Tree Express</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Green Tree Pro</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Wobbler 3.0</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Coolkid</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                    <h4>Education</h4>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Learn Thai</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Math Genius</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Chemokid</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                    <h4>Professionals</h4>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Success 1.0</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Moneymaker</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
                </li>
                <li>    <a href="#">Downloads</a>

                    <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                        <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
                            <div>
                                    <h4>Education &amp; Learning</h4>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Learn Thai</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Math Genius</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Chemokid</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                    <h4>Professionals</h4>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Success 1.0</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Moneymaker</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                    <h4>Entertainment</h4>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Gadget Finder</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Green Tree Express</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Green Tree Pro</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Holy Cannoli</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Wobbler 3.0</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Coolkid</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                    <h4>Games</h4>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Catch the Bullet</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Snoopydoo</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Fallen Angel</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sui Maker</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Wave Master</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Golf Pro</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
                </li>
                <li>    <a href="#">Applications</a>

                    <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                        <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
                            <div>
                                    <h4>Learning &amp; Games</h4>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Catch the Bullet</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Snoopydoo</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                    <h4>Utilities</h4>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Gadget Finder</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Green Tree Express</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Green Tree Pro</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Wobbler 3.0</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Coolkid</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                    <h4>Education</h4>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Learn Thai</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Math Genius</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Chemokid</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                    <h4>Professionals</h4>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Success 1.0</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Moneymaker</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
                </li>
                <li>    <a href="#">Projects</a>

                    <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                        <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
                            <div>
                                    <h4>Learning &amp; Games</h4>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Catch the Bullet</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Snoopydoo</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Fallen Angel</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sui Maker</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Wave Master</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Golf Pro</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                    <h4>Utilities</h4>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Gadget Finder</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Green Tree Express</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                    <h4>Entertainment</h4>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Gadget Finder</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Green Tree Express</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Green Tree Pro</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Holy Cannoli</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Wobbler 3.0</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Coolkid</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
                </li>
                <li>    <a href="#">Freeware</a>

                    <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                        <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
                            <div>
                                    <h4>Utilities</h4>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Green Tree Pro</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Wobbler 3.0</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Coolkid</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                    <h4>Education</h4>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Learn Thai</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Math Genius</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Chemokid</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                    <h4>Professionals</h4>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Success 1.0</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Moneymaker</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                    <h4>Learning &amp; Games</h4>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Catch the Bullet</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Snoopydoo</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Fallen Angel</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sui Maker</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Wave Master</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Golf Pro</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the code after beautifying and changes

```
var cbpHorizontalMenu = (function () {
    var b = $("#cbp-hrmenu > ul > li"),
        g = b.children("a"),
        c = $("body"),
        d = -1;

    function f() {
        g.on("mouseover", a);
        b.on("mouseover", function (h) {
            h.stopPropagation()
        })
    }

    function a(j) {
        if (d !== -1) {
            b.eq(d).removeClass("cbp-hropen")
        }
        var i = $(j.currentTarget).parent("li"),
            h = i.index();
        if (d === h) {
            i.removeClass("cbp-hropen");
            d = -1
        } else {
            i.addClass("cbp-hropen");
            d = h;
            c.off("click").on("click", e)
        }
        return false
    }

    function e(h) {
        b.eq(d).removeClass("cbp-hropen");
        d = -1
    }
    return {
        init: f
    }
})();

$(function () {
    cbpHorizontalMenu.init();
});
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/q9HfR/)

Comment: It works on mouseHover but it keeps the menu even if i move move out of the menu are `Blue Area` How can i hide menu when mouse moves out of menu area

Comment: Add an event listener for "mouseout" an when it fires then hide the menu again (like it was before hovering)

Comment: Cool, I also noticed that it hides the same menu if we hover twice over same menu

Comment: Perhaps, I just did a quick hack to show you that minimised javascript from some other website can be beautified to make it readable and then you can make changes to their code and their html to suit your own needs. Perhaps the code needs a complete rewrite to match your requirements, but with very a small change it was nearly there with little effort.

Comment: Functionality should be similar to this menu http://demos.pixelworkshop.fr/css3_mega_menu/

Comment: Yes, that looks quite a nice menu and it looks like it may be 100% CSS

Answer (score 1):

```
 var cbpHorizontalMenu = (function () {
var b = jQuery("#cbp-hrmenu > ul > li"),
    g = b.children("a"),
    c = $("body"),
    d = -1;

function f() {
 g.on("mouseenter", a);

 b.on("mouseenter", function (h) { h.stopPropagation(); });
}

function a(j) {
    if (d !== -1) {
      b.eq(d).removeClass("cbp-hropen");
    }
    var i = jQuery(j.currentTarget).parent("li"),
        h = i.index();

    if (d == h)  {           
        i.addClass("cbp-hropen");
        d = h;
        //alert(h);
    }
    else if (d === h) {
        i.removeClass("cbp-hropen");
        d = -1 
    } else {

        i.addClass("cbp-hropen");
        d = h;
        c.off("mouseenter").on("mouseenter", e)
    }
    return false
}

function e(h) {
   b.eq(d).removeClass("cbp-hropen");
   d = -1
}
return {
    init: f
}
```

})();

Answer (score 0):

Only one function needs to be modified

```
function f() {
    g.on("mouseover", a); b.on("mouseover", function (h) { h.stopPropagation() });
}
```

Replace "click" with "mouseover"

Comment: Nope, the menu doesn't close then if you leave the menu item.

Comment: Yes, but if you click anywhere on the document then menu will be closed.

Comment: Yea but the website visitor will be annoyed if it doesn't close automatically :)

Comment: I appreciate your responses but i want this menu to function like a normal drop down menu found on most of the website. If we use it with click event then it can frustrate most user as user dont usually click on the menu as they expect it to be a mouse Hover king of event..